# Why can't nucleotides when mixed together form an RNA on their own?

Tags: rna

Why nucleotides when mixed together in the absence of a template
RNA molecule do not readily link up into a chain? We know that the bond between nucleotides side by side is stronger than the hydrogen bond between the two RNA strands, a negative and a positive one. Shouldn't then the nucleotides form chains of RNA more readily by just attaching to each other than making a dimeric RNA through a lock and key type latching?

The book that caused this question is "What Is Life?" by A. Pross (p.68), who unfortunately doesn't provide an answer.

Comment: Before asking questions about the chemistry of biological reactions you should learn some basic chemistry. This [online resource](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22567/) may help. The role of enzymes in relation to the [thermodynamics of reactions](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22584/#A1024) is also key.

Comment: RNA nucleotides will form chains spontaneously, having a catalyst however makes it happen faster.

Answer (score -1):

The dNTPs don't just come together. They require a polymerase to break off 2 phosphates and bond the hydroxyl group to the remaining phosphate. To take a nucleotide triphosphate and add it to a growing chain of nucleic acid, the polymerase checks the fidelity of the hydrogen bonds that precede the new bond. dNTPs provide the energy for this reaction, but the enzymes require a double stranded molecule to copy. In other words, they can copy double stranded nucleic acid, but not form it from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I only would like to clarify if the same laws apply to the self-replicating RNA (autocatalytic), with no enzymes, since the book is talking about prebiotic time.

Comment: @Karl: DNA polymerase theta is capable of template-independent DNA synthesis. Kent et al. (2016) Elife 5: e13740. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27311885